# Command Aliasing in Thor

Tags: ruby, thor

Is it possible to create aliases for commands in Thor?

Much like command aliasing in Commander. https://github.com/tj/commander#command-aliasing

I am able to find aliases for options, but not for the command itself.

Using the example from Thor,

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'thor'

# cli.rb
class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"
  def hello(name)
    puts "Hello #{name}"
  end
end

MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```

I should be able to run

```
$ ./cli.rb hello John
Hello John
```

I would like to alias the command "hello" to "hi" as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use map for this:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor#map-class_method

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'thor'

# cli.rb
class MyCLI < Thor

  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"
  def hello(name)
    puts "Hello #{name}"
  end

  map 'hi' => :hello
end

MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```

Comment: Seems that new versions of Thor expect the mapping parameter to be a string or an array and value a symbol. See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor#map-class_method

Comment: In this case it would be `map "hi" => :hello`

Answer (score -3):

Use **method_option** for aliases.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
    require 'thor'

    # cli.rb
    class MyCLI < Thor
      desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"
      method_option :hello , :aliases => "-hello" , :desc => "Hello Command" 
      def hello(name)
        puts "Hello #{name}"
      end
    end

    MyCLI.start(ARGV)
```